# Google Cloud Messaging Error:SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I think that there is a problem in the manifest but i can't find it.

When invoke

> > gcm.register(Constant.SENDER_ID);

I have this error:

> Error:SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

This is manifest file, only the Gcm definition:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:name="com.sweng.easyplacemaster.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sweng.easyplacemaster.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<receiver
        android:name="com.sweng.easyplacemaster.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.sweng.easyplacemaster" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.sweng.easyplacemaster.gcm.GCMIntentService" />
    <service android:name="com.sweng.easyplacemaster.gcm.RegistrationService" />
```

This is my BroadcastReceiver:

```
package com.sweng.easyplacemaster.gcm;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * @author Paolo
 *
 */
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver 
    {

        private static final String TAG = "GcmBroadcastReceiver";



        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GCMIntentService.class.getName());
                Log.i(TAG, "Begin Broadcast");

                startWakefulService(context, intent.setComponent(comp));

                setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
            }
    }
```

This is my IntentService:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.sweng.easyplacemaster.gcm;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.sweng.easyplacemaster.R;
import com.sweng.easyplacemaster.dashboard.Start_Activity;
import com.sweng.easyplacemaster.utility.Constant;

/**
 * @author Paolo
 *
 */
public class GCMIntentService extends IntentService 
    {
        public static final String TAG = "GcmIntentService";
        public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

        public GCMIntentService()
            {
                super(Constant.SENDER_ID);
            }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.IntentService#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            // Prendo l'istanza di Google Cloud Messaging
            GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

            // Prendo la stringa che mi indica il tipo di messaggio
            String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

            Log.i( TAG , "Messaggio ricevuto: " + extras.toString());

            if(!extras.isEmpty())
                {   
                    // Azione nel caso il messaggio sia di errore
                    if(GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType))
                        sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
                    // Azione nel caso il messaggio sia riguardo l'eliminazione sul server
                    else if(GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType))
                        sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
                    // Azione nel caso sia un messaggio rigardante la nostra applicazione
                    else if(GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType))
                        {
                           SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this) ;

                                    Intent i = new Intent();
                                    i.setAction(Constant.CUSTOM_ACTION);
                                    i.putExtra("message", extras.getString("message"));
                                    this.sendBroadcast(i);


                                    sendNotification(extras.getString("message"));
                        }
                }

            WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        }
```

Comment: What device are you testing this on? Did you ensure that it has the latest version of Google Play Services?

Comment: I am testing with Emulator, but it worked. After i split some classes in different packages and i got this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you create api key in google console?

Comment: Yes Api Key and Project Number.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the device /emulator is connected to the internet before starting the IntentService